# Giving line by line input to stdin

Tags: bash, shell

I have a command that takes input iteratively through stdin until EOF is encountered. I want to automate this process by writing a shell script which would read each line from a file and feed it to this command. I am not able to figure out how to go about feeding the lines for stdin.

```
FILENAME=$1
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
    java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.4.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.4-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-0.23.jar -mx2g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -stdin < $LINE
done
```

But I am getting a "Ambiguous Redirect" error. I am just starting out in shell scripting. I don't know how to go about this

EDIT: I changed the code so that the program is not started every time

```
FILENAME=$1
while read LINE
do
    java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.4.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.4-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-0.23.jar -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -stdin < $LINE
done <$FILENAME
```

Comment: You do not need `cat` for the loop, just use `done < "$FILENAME"` at the end. If you use this kind of loop, your program will be started for each line in the file. Is that what you want?

Comment: No. I don't want that. I will change that then. But what about each line?

Comment: Try `java ... <<<"$LINE"` or `java ... <(echo "$LINE")`.

Comment: Why must you use a `while` loop? Can't a single line command: `java ... < $FILENAME` work correctly??

Comment: Yes it did! I didn't realize file input would read line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Java program reads from the standard input line by line, while you want it to read from a file, you just do:

```
java -cp xxx.jar YourProgram < "Path/to/the/file"
```

, which will work perfectly with your program.

There is no need to read the file line by line by yourself in a script!